# How can I configure WinRAR to open the folder after extracting?

Tags: winrar

Is there a way to automatically open the folder extracted from WinRAR?

Can I also configure WinRAR to open the folder only when I extract from the GUI, and not from the Explorer right-click context menu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be configured in WinRAR with the *Display files in Explorer* option on the extract dialog, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: WinRAR extract dialog]

Enabling it will work for the current archive but any further archives extracted will have this option disabled. To ensure it sticks for all archives just click the *Save settings* button underneath, then it will apply to all archives being extracted in the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, even tho it 8 months old, i still had no idea how to do this. cool. +1/accept

Comment: Glad I could help :)